# Upgrade MongoDB from 2.6 to 3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, upgrade, ubuntu-16.04

I have Ubuntu 16.04 machine with MongoDB 2.6 install.

Now I want to upgrade MongoDB to latest version, i.e., 3.4

What is the best way to Upgrade?

From MongoDB website, I found that, I must have to follow step by step upgrade. e.g, 2.6 to 3.0, then 3.0 to 3.2, then 3.2 to 3.4 Is this correct?

What is the best and safe way to upgrade MongoDB, so I can complete it with less down time?

Comment: Today I tried following things for this Upgrade

Comment: vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
Executing: /tmp/tmp.3VqvFct3lr/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv
7F0CEB10
gpg: requesting key 7F0CEB10 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 7F0CEB10: public key "Richard Kreuter <richard@10gen.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)

Comment: vagrant@vagrant:~$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse

Comment: vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                  
Ign:2 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 InRelease                            
Get:3 http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.0 Release [3,462 B]

Comment: Last week I was upgraded mongodb from 2.6.4 to 3.2 directly (mongodump  + mongorestore  ) , up to now my project worked perfectly.

Comment: vagrant@vagrant:/usr$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-04-06T06:19:32.382+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-04-06T06:19:32.382+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed